# How do I list samba user accounts that need synchronizing?

Tags: samba

From searching, I have found a lot of suggestions for synchronizing the unix account and the samba account using smbpasswd, but how do I tell which accounts need synchronizing, and which accounts are already synchronized? If I cannot get this information, is it at least possible to get a list of those user accounts that have a samba password set?

Answer (score 1):

Try this command in the terminal:

```
sudo pdbedit -w -L | awk -F: '{print $1}'
```

For more options [refer this link](http://ubuntuforums.org/showpost.php?p=4674173&postcount=12).

Comment: Thanks, but how do I know which accounts are synchronized, and which need synchronizing?